# Python codeacademy error

Tags: python

> **Instructions:** Write an if statement that verifies that the string has characters.
>
> Add an if statement that checks that `len(original)` is greater than
>   zero. Don't forget the `:` at the end of the if statement! If the
>   string actually has some characters in it, print the user's word.
>   Otherwise (i.e. an else: statement), please print "empty". You'll want
>   to run your code multiple times, testing an empty string and a string
>   with characters. When you're confident your code works, continue to
>   the next exercise.

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'

# Start coding here!
if len(original) > 0:
    return True
else len(original) <= 0
    return False
original = raw_input("Enter a word:")

print original
print "empty"
```

I'm stuck as I keep getting the following error. What am I doing wrong?

```
File "python", line 6
   else len(original) = 0
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not have a check condition on an else

```
if len(original) > 0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

So your full answer should look something like (Based upon the description of what it wants you to do that you provided, **NOT** the direction you were going in):

```
original = raw_input("Enter a word:")
if len(original) > 0:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is your code, it won't work at all because it will `return` before it does anything
your `print original` should replace the return True, and `print empty` should replace return False

After removing everything after `else` on that line of course (and including the `:`)

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'
original = raw_input("Enter a word:")

# Start coding here!
if len(original) > 0:
    print original
else:
    print 'empty'
```

-- Or --

```
print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'
original = raw_input("Enter a word:")
result = original if len(original) > 0 else 'empty'
print result
```

Comment: @KevinDTimm lets not scare him now...he is just beginning :p

Comment: Sorry, I can't help myself when I see these opportunities to introduce the ternary operator!

Comment: haha @heinst i was stuck looking at that ternary operator like "huh"

Comment: That's not valid syntax in Python. The correct ternary operator is `original if len(original) > 0 else "empty"`.

Comment: @Navith - almost but not quite.  I have fixed it in the post. <editorial>Unfortunately this 'ruins' the ternary operator in that it doesn't really jump out at you when you see it.</editorial>